# Python for loop only running once

Tags: python, for-loop, user-interface, tkinter, foreach

This program takes multiple directories that have the [Plex movie file structure](https://support.plex.tv/articles/naming-and-organizing-your-tv-show-files/) and outputs all the movies, resolutions, file paths, etc into a .csv file. It was all working perfectly until I moved this application to a simple GUI using [rumps](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps). All that I had to do was move my existing code into separate functions and I did exactly that, but now my essential for loop that scans each directory in a list of directories only runs once when directoryList has two or more elements in it.

```
for directory in directoryList: #for each directory chosen by the user
```

I've been looking at this for hours but I am not sure how to fix it. [Here is my entire code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wU85GGju)

This is where the for loop should move on to the second directory given in the directory list but just stops. As I said it worked totally fine when it was only command line. Any guesses as to what I did wrong?
[image]

Comment: One of the first ways I learned to debug my program was to litter my code with `print` statements that showed important variable values. Have you tried any additional debugging methods past narrowing it down to this loop?

Comment: can you add a try-except block to see if an exception is being thrown during the processing of for loop content?

Comment: @SunnyPatel I did have a ton of commented out print statements that I deleted so my code was more presentable haha. One weird thing I found was that if I initialized setupFiles to False and then changed it's value to True in setup() function then when I ran the scanMovies() function it would still be False. I don't know how this relates to my for loop but just throwing that out there

Comment: @mjkool just added a try-except block and it seems on the second iteration of the loop it throws an exception of some kind

Comment: @mjkool To further expand on what I said, it throws a Errno 2] No such file or directory: '' which is weird because my directory list contains ['/Volumes/Top Spec/Media/Movies', '/Volumes/1TB WD Blue/Media/Movies'] so it's like deleting my second index or completely deleting the whole list